# t-SQL: Incorrect Syntax Near 'Go'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> *note: I have already reviewed several similar questions both on SO and on other forums, none of the suggestions have proven useful.*

The following t-SQL script works just fine:

```
USE [MASTER]
GO
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT name  
     FROM master.sys.server_principals
     WHERE name = 'myTestUser')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'CREATING LOGIN: [myTestUser]'
    CREATE LOGIN [myTestUser] WITH PASSWORD = N'P@55w0rd'
END ELSE BEGIN
    PRINT 'LOGIN [myTestUser] already exists on this server.'
        END
END
GO
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
            WHERE name ='myTestDb' 
        )
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'CREATING DATABASE [myTestDb]'
            --INSERT CREATE DB SCRIPT --
        END ELSE BEGIN      
            PRINT 'DATABASE [myTestDb] already exists on this server'
        END;
END
GO
USE[myTestDb]
```

The following script **ALSO** works fine:

```
use [master]
CREATE DATABASE [myTestDb]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'myTestDb', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\myTestDb.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'myTestDb_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\myTestDb_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
--I have several ALTER DATABASE commands to follow, this is the minimum    
--necessary to duplicate the error condition.
```

HOWEVER When the second script is dropped inside the first script *(less the USE [master] line)* at the point where it reads: --INSERT CREATE DB SCRIPT-- I get

> Incorrect Syntax Near 'Go'

on the first 'Go'...
If I remove the 'Go' the error moves to the next instance of 'Go'..
The LAST 'Go' is critical (before the new USE)

Comment: Can you post the actual script that is having problems?

Comment: I have tested this sample and it provides the same errors, in the same spot. The actual name of the user or the Db should not be the issue.

Comment: So, your first script ends with `USE [myTestDb]`, and the second one starts with `use [master]`. Why change the first script from `Master` to `myTestDb`?

Comment: The go is inside begin - end block. That can't work.

Comment: `GO` is a batch separator in SSMS, but _not_ a TSQL statement. Using it within an `IF` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Before USE [myTestDb] I am confirming/creating the login and db to be used. Following the second 'USE' I plan to assign the login and create tables and initialize data. If I don't execute that last GO SSIS will block the execution if [myTestDb] doesn't exist.

Comment: @HABO - I was thinking it would create a 'sub batch' inside the BEGIN/END block under the if.

Comment: Where have you found a "sub batch" documented? [Batches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are independent collections of statements to be executed. They don't nest, call one another, ... .

Comment: My {misplaced} belief that it would work was more based on the operation of the BEGIN...END statements as code blocks. I thought the batch would operate as a child of the block... (like scope...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you paste the second script into the first, are you including the GO at the bottom of the second script, so that the combined script looks like this?

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
    WHERE name ='myTestDb' 
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'CREATING DATABASE [myTestDb]'
    CREATE DATABASE [myTestDb]
        CONTAINMENT = NONE
        ON  PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'myTestDb', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\myTestDb.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
        LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'myTestDb_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\myTestDb_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
    GO
END ELSE BEGIN      
    PRINT 'DATABASE [myTestDb] already exists on this server'
END;
```

If so, the problem is that you have a `GO` in the middle of an `IF...ELSE` construct. Try moving the `GO` so it's after the `END`, like so:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
    WHERE name ='myTestDb' 
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'CREATING DATABASE [myTestDb]'
    CREATE DATABASE [myTestDb]
        CONTAINMENT = NONE
        ON  PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'myTestDb', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\myTestDb.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
        LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'myTestDb_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\myTestDb_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
END ELSE BEGIN      
    PRINT 'DATABASE [myTestDb] already exists on this server'
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you, this identified the solution!